# DeviceTwin issue in updating properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-iot-hub

I have a problem updating a property attribute with DeviceTwin in c #.

The code I execute is the following:

```
            var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(AppSettings.KeyIoT);
            var twin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(dto.DeviceIdorId);

            TwinCollection s = twin.Properties.Reported["Power"];

            Power toRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Power>(s.ToJson());
            toRet.MaximumAvailable = 50;

           var patch =
            @"{
            properties: {
                reported:{
                  Power:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toRet) +
                @"}
                }
            }";

            await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, patch, twin.ETag);
```

I tried also with the following code :

```
            var registryManager = RegistryManager.CreateFromConnectionString(AppSettings.KeyIoT);
            var twin = await registryManager.GetTwinAsync(dto.DeviceIdorId);

            TwinCollection s = twin.Properties.Reported["Power"];

            Power toRet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Power>(s.ToJson());
            toRet.MaximumAvailable = 50;

            twin.Properties.Reported["Power"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toRet);

            Twin updatedTwin = await registryManager.UpdateTwinAsync(twin.DeviceId, twin, twin.ETag);
```

The problem is that after the update, if I do a reread, the property MaximumAvailable is not updated.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: "a problem"??? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: @IanMercer : I have updated the post.

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51768883/updatetwinasync-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device twin *reported* properties are **readonly** on the service-facing side. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins)

Comment: If I change reported with desidered I get the following error : **"Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object. Path 'properties.desidered', line 4, position 112."}"** What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: your code with a patch implementation (the first one) is working well. Did you change a *reported* to the *desired* in the patch json formatted text, too?

Comment: Yes, I changed a reported to the desidered in the patch Json formatted text and I got the error.